# Ruby - Unpack array with mixed types

Tags: ruby, binaryfiles, binary-data, pack, unpack

I am trying to use `unpack` to decode a binary file. The binary file has the following structure:

```
ABCDEF\tFFFABCDEF\tFFFF....
```

where

```
ABCDEF -> String of fixed length
\t -> tab character
FFF -> 3 Floats
.... -> repeat thousands of times
```

I know how to do it when types are all the same or with only numbers and fixed length arrays, but I am struggling in this situation. For example, if I had a list of floats I would do

```
s.unpack('F*')
```

Or if I had integers and floats like

```
[1, 3.4, 5.2, 4, 2.3, 7.8]
```

I would do

```
s.unpack('CF2CF2')
```

But in this case I am a bit lost. I was hoping to use a format string such `(CF2)*' with brackets, but it does not work.

**I need to use Ruby 2.0.0-p247 if that matters**

**Example**

```
ary = ["ABCDEF\t", 3.4, 5.6, 9.1, "FEDCBA\t", 2.5, 8.9, 3.1]
s = ary.pack('P7fffP7fff')
```

then

```
s.scan(/.{19}/)
["\xA8lf\xF9\xD4\x7F\x00\x00\x9A\x99Y@33\xB3@\x9A\x99\x11", "A\x80lf\xF9\xD4\x7F\x00\x00\x00\x00 @ff\x0EAff"]
```

Finally

```
s.scan(/.{19}/).map{ |item| item.unpack('P7fff') }
Error: #<ArgumentError: no associated pointer>
<main>:in `unpack'
<main>:in `block in <main>'
<main>:in `map'
<main>:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The `P7` is the issue, try changing just to lowercase `p` (no 7). There is some differences when packing/unpacking. When reading the file, you use the `P7` because it is not null-terminates, but when packing it again, it is. I just used the example without error by packing with `P7fffP7fff` and unpacking with `pfffpfff`.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Your example uses an array where each item is already separated, so you will be using lower `p`. When reading the file, it is going to be a string of bytes without a being separated into array items, so you must specify the fixed length with the uppercase variant `P7`.

Comment: OK. I will try tonight when I go back home and get access to the file.

Comment: @ForeverZer0: Both `p` and `P` are the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the file in small chunks of 19 bytes and use `'A7fff'` to pack and unpack. Do not use pointers to structure (`'p'` and `'P'`), as they need more than 19 bytes to encode your information.
You could also use `'A6xfff'` to ignore the 7th byte and get a string with 6 chars.

Here's an example, which is similar to the documentation of [`IO.read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-read):

```
data = [["ABCDEF\t", 3.4, 5.6, 9.1], 
        ["FEDCBA\t", 2.5, 8.9, 3.1]]
binary_file = 'data.bin'
chunk_size = 19
pattern = 'A7fff'

File.open(binary_file, 'wb') do |o|
  data.each do |row|
    o.write row.pack(pattern)
  end
end

raise "Something went wrong. Please check data, pattern and chunk_size." unless File.size(binary_file) == data.length * chunk_size

File.open(binary_file, 'rb') do |f|
  while record = f.read(chunk_size)
    puts '%s %g %g %g' % record.unpack(pattern)
  end
end
# =>
#    ABCDEF   3.4 5.6 9.1
#    FEDCBA   2.5 8.9 3.1
```

You could use a multiple of `19` to speed up the process if your file is large.

Comment: `A7fff` did the trick. Even without writing to file I can unpack it with `s.scan(/.{19}/).map{ |item| item.unpack('A7fff') }`

Comment: @Rojj: Sure, you don't have to write anything if you already have your data. It was just to have a common binary data to debug and test. `scan` also works, but it needs to have the whole file in memory, which might not be suitable if you work with large files.

Comment: @Rojj: If you don't care about the last character of the string, you could also use `'A6xfff'`, as in `["ABCDEF\t", 3.4, 5.6, 9.1].pack('A7fff').unpack('A6xfff')`

Comment: Oh that's great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with mixed formats that repeat, and are of a known fixed size, it is often easier to split the string first,

Quick example would be:

```
binary.scan(/.{LENGTH_OF_DATA}/).map { |item| item.unpack(FORMAT) }
```

Considering your above example, take the length of the string including the tab character (in bytes), plus the size of a 3 floats. If your strings are literally `'ABCDEF\t'`, you would use a size of 19 (7 for the string, 12 for the 3 floats).

Your final product would look like this:

```
str.scan(/.{19}/).map { |item| item.unpack('P7fff') }
```

Per example:

```
irb(main):001:0> ary = ["ABCDEF\t", 3.4, 5.6, 9.1, "FEDCBA\t", 2.5, 8.9, 3.1]
=> ["ABCDEF\t", 3.4, 5.6, 9.1, "FEDCBA\t", 2.5, 8.9, 3.1]

irb(main):002:0> s = ary.pack('pfffpfff')
=> "\xE8Pd\xE4eU\x00\x00\x9A\x99Y@33\xB3@\x9A\x99\x11A\x98Pd\xE4eU\x00\x00\x00\x00 @ff\x0EAffF@"

irb(main):003:0> s.unpack('pfffpfff')
=> ["ABCDEF\t", 3.4000000953674316, 5.599999904632568, 9.100000381469727, "FEDCBA\t", 2.5, 8.899999618530273, 3.0999999046325684]
```

The minor differences in precision is unavoidable, but do not worry about it, as it comes from the difference of a 32-bit float and 64-bit double (what Ruby used internally), and the precision difference will be less than is significant for a 32-bit float.

Comment: Beautiful, but I have a problem. I read the string from the file with `File.binread'. This gives me a `String` and `String` does not have the method `each_slice`. I tried to convert it to `bytes` or `chars`, but this gives me arrays and unpack does not work on arrays. Does `each_slice` work on string for Ruby 2.0.0?

Comment: My apologies, I corrected answer to use `String#scan` instead of `each_slice`. You could alternatively use `str.chars.each_slice`, but `scan` is a cleaner approach IMO.

Comment: I get `no associated pointer`. I have added an example so we look at exactly the same thing.

Comment: `p` / `P` are not the correct directive here. Use `a` as in `a6x` (x to ignore tab character) as `P7` means seven pointers to Ruby strings.

Comment: A lowercase `p` means that, but for uppercase `P`, it indicates the size of the struct. Demonstrated easily with `['stack', 'overflow'].pack('pp').unpack('P5P8')`. It does not try to unpack 13 pointers.

Comment: The problem is that `pack('pfff')` does not create a 19-byte binary string.

Comment: There would be an added null byte, but OP question is regarding reading from a file, the entire lowercase `p` is just some explanation stuff with his example. 'a' would be better option if he is writing it back to avoid any inclusion of a null-terminator.

Comment: @ForeverZer0: All I'm saying is that `str.scan(/.{19}/).map { |item| item.unpack('P7fff') }` is wrong and won't work with OP's data. I'd be happy to revert the downvote if you change the pattern. Is there any particular reason why you downvoted my answer?

Comment: Finally, it might not be a good idea to read the large file in memory and create a large array with `scan` if it's possible to process the data sequentially.

Comment: I agree, slurping the entire file is bad practice, can edit later, mobile ATM. I truly didn't downvote you. I only ever downvote anybody if it is objectively incorrect, never just for style and/or efficiency etc.